# Downvoting "marginal" posts can trigger their inclusion into Low Quality queue?

Tags: support, down-votes, answer-quality, review

Recently I reviewed some posts using SEDE query called ["Marginal short answers with links"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8599945#8599945).

- <sup>For the record, I have been using query parameters [as suggested here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8600254#8600254), with the only difference that min value was set `-2` instead of `0`, for I wanted to additionally review posts indicating some sort of "community disapproval".</sup>

While reviewing posts listed in query results I downvoted some of these (["pulled a Gnat"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8605062#8605062) as they say:). Soon after that, I noticed that many of the posts I DVed popped in Low Quality review queue:
[1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24599),
[2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24600),
[3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24601),
[4](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24602),
[5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24603),
[6](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24604).

Given that mentioned posts were laying dormant for quite a long time (year or more), it looks like my votes triggered their inclusion into queue. Is that observation correct? If yes, I also would want to understand whether such a *dependency of downvotes* is intended by queue design?

---

#### Update

Two days later I repeated experiment like above and, voila, 8 more posts were added to the queue:
[7](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24768),
[8](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24769),
[9](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24770),
[10](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24771),
[11](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24772),
[12](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24773),
[13](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24774),
[14](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24776). Next day experiment brought yet another 5 posts into the queue:
[15](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24875),
[16](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24876),
[17](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24877),
[18](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24878),
[19](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24879).

What I noticed in repeated experiments is that queue was populated with posts that got zero score because of my downvote. It looks like quite a reliable pattern of *cause-effect*.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, there was [yet another example](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24605) besides those listed above, but after pondering on it I decided to edit and undownvote. It wasn't included in the list to keep the question simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my reading of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150253/165773) written by SE developer, downvotes increase chances of the post getting into Low Quality queue:

> approach to low-quality auto-flagging, by looking for similarities in posts **downvoted** or flagged as low quality...

It is worth noting that per mentioned answer, upvotes tend to have an opposite effect:

> referenced post got 2 upvotes..., so it **wouldn't even make it into** the low quality queue

---

Those interested to know how Low Quality queue is expected to work, can refer to [respective guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/165773):

> ### Guidelines for reviewing Low Quality Posts
>
> Questions appear in the low quality post queue both by algorithm and [by flags from users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/167534).
>
> #### Basic workflow
>
> 1. Check if the post can be improved. If it can, by all means **Edit** it. A typical example are code-only answers, which can benefit from additional explanation about how that code works.
> 2. If you think the post is unsalvageable and should be deleted, **Recommend Deletion** (see common reasons below).
> 3. If the post looks good, choose **Looks Good**. If you are unsure, **Skip** it...